# How much time is the Tekia of Shofar supposed to take?

Tags: time, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

When one blows Shofar on Rosh HaShana, how much time is the Tekia supposed to take in order to be Yotzei the Mitzva?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- As long as the Shevarim-Teruah in TaShRa"T
- As long as the Shevarim in TaSha"T
- As long as the Teruah in TaRa"T

Source [Shulchan Aruch HaRav 590:7](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh4/2/590/7)

---

As to how long the Shevarim and the Teruah have to be, it depends on the definition of the Teruah. It is 3 Yevavot (not quite sure how to translate that, see Talmud Rosh Hashanah 33B), and according to some opinions a Yevava is 1 staccato blast, and according to others it is 3 staccato blasts.

A Shevarim need to last as long as a Teruah.

Therefore, according to the first opinion:

- Tekiah as long as the Shevarim-Teruah in TaShRa"T == the length of 6 short blasts
- Tekiah as long as the Shevarim in TaSha"T == the length of 3 short blasts
- Tekiah as long as the Teruah in TaRa"T == the length of 3 short blasts

According to the second opinion:

- Tekiah as long as the Shevarim-Teruah in TaShRa"T == the length of 18 short blasts
- Tekiah as long as the Shevarim in TaSha"T == the length of 9 short blasts
- Tekiah as long as the Teruah in TaRa"T == the length of 9 short blasts

Source: [Shulchan Aruch HaRav 590:4-6](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh4/2/590/index.htm)

---

LeHalacha, The Shulchan Aruch HaRav (590:7) says that one should LeChatchila follow the second opinion. Bedieved he fulfills his obligation if he followed the first opinion. If he mixed up the two opinions in such a way that he would not have fulfilled it according to either of the two opinions he must redo it.